# Ajax Loading different content through links

Tags: jquery, ajax, addclass

what i am trying to do, when i click a tab, the address bar url should also change to that action plus it should also add the class to the anchor tag.

This is very nice example in jsfiddle, that i have seen someone shared on stackoverflow.
http://jsfiddle.net/VcQKr/2/

but problem here is that it works of adding and removing of class for li tag, but when i change this line
from

```
$parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

to

```
$t.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

then it only add classes to anchor tag but it dont remove classes from it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `a` elements are not siblings in your markup, you should select the siblings of the parent and remove the class from their `a` descendant elements.

```
$(this).addClass("selected")
       .parent()
       .siblings()
       .find('a')
       .removeClass("selected");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvxrL/

Comment: Thankyou Sir, Very Nice. Now i understand how it works. Thankyou.